# Inserting only unique values in objectbox entity

Tags: objectbox

Is there something similar to this: @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE) as found in Room database that you can do in Objectbox.  If not, how can you avoid saving duplicate entries in an objectbox entity?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

in object box DataModel class, make the item anotation

> @unique
>   Public String userID;

---

```
private Box<User> userBox;
userBox = ObjectBox.get().boxFor(User.class);

//your inserted object 

if (!userBox.getAll().contains(insertedObject)){
                        leadBoxForLeadOpions.put(l);
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replacing objects should be simple enough as setting the `@id(assignable=true)` annotation to the wanted id field. I have tested it in my android app via:

```
@Test
fun testAssignableIdsGetReplaced() {
    val myUser1 = User()
    myUser1.id = 1
    myUser1.nickname = "Original"
    var currentList = boxStore!!.boxFor(User::class.java).all
    assert(currentList.size == 0)
    boxStore!!.boxFor(User::class.java).put(myUser1)
    currentList = boxStore!!.boxFor(User::class.java).all
    assert(currentList.size == 1)
    assert(currentList.get(0).id == 1L)
    val newUser1 = User()
    newUser1.id = 1
    newUser1.nickname = "New"
    boxStore!!.boxFor(User::class.java).put(newUser1)
    currentList = boxStore!!.boxFor(User::class.java).all
    assert(currentList.size == 1)
    assert(currentList.get(0).id == 1L)
    assert(currentList.get(0).nickname == newUser1.nickname)
}

@Entity
class User() {
  @Id(assignable = true) var id: Long = 0
  lateinitvar nickname: String
}
```

But bare in mind that using ids assignable annotation may produce sideeffects:
https://docs.objectbox.io/relations#updating-relations
https://docs.objectbox.io/advanced/object-ids#self-assigned-object-ids

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `@Unique()` annotation in the field you wanna make unique, like this:

```dart
@Entity()
class FooEntity {
  @Id()
  int id;//some id

  @Unique()
  int fooField;//unique field
}
```

By objectBox docs:

```dart
/// Enforces that the value of a property is unique among all objects in a box
/// before an object can be put.
///
/// Trying to put an object with offending values will result in a
/// [UniqueViolationException] (see [ConflictStrategy.fail]).
/// Set [onConflict] to change this strategy.
///
/// Note: Unique properties are based on an [Index], so the same restrictions apply.
/// It is supported to explicitly add the [Index] annotation to configure the
/// index.
class Unique {
  /// The strategy to use when a conflict is detected when an object is put.
  final ConflictStrategy onConflict;

  /// Create a Unique annotation.
  const Unique({this.onConflict = ConflictStrategy.fail});
}
```

```dart
/// Used with [Unique] to specify the conflict resolution strategy.
enum ConflictStrategy {
  /// Throws [UniqueViolationException] if any property violates a [Unique] constraint.
  fail,

  /// Any conflicting objects are deleted before the object is inserted.
  replace,
}
```

By default you will have the fail behavior, it mean, if the value in `fooField` is already storaged, an error will be throw by objetbox. In the other hand, if you put the `onConflict` property in the `Unique` annotation to `ConflictStrategy.replace`, the object will be replaced.

The final approuch will be like this:

```dart
@Entity()
class FooEntity {
  @Id()
  int id;//some id

  @Unique(onConflict: ConflictStrategy.replace)
  int fooField;
}
```

If you wanna make it on the id of the class, just use the `Unique` and `Id` on the same field. Like this:

```dart
@Entity()
class FooEntity {
  @Id()
  @Unique(onConflict: ConflictStrategy.replace)
  int id;//some id

  int fooField;
}
```

Hope this solve the problem. It did it for my.